# What are the dimensions of the backyard?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was able to determine that the area not covered by the pool is $32$ square meters, and the areas represent the sequence $a(n) = 16n$. I just can't figure out how to find the dimensions of the backyard.

> Steve is helping his uncle dig a pool in his uncle's backyard.  The backyard is a rectangle with an area of $48~\text{m}^2$.  If Steve's uncle wants to put in a square pool with area $16~\text{m}^2$, determine the following: 
>  a.  The area of the backyard that will not be covered by the pool 
>  b. The dimensions of the backyard

[image]

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: Please type your work since some readers rely on screen readers that may be unable to read images.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your work, I think you might have missed that the pool is square. Knowing that it’s square with an area of 16 m<sup>2</sup> makes us able to figure out how large the sides of the pool are. Since the pool has to fit into the backyard, we can then figure out the minimum width and height of the backyard and can give a few options for its dimensions.

Let me know if this hint helped or if you want another one!

Comment: When I set up the system of equations $hw = 48$ and $(h - 4)(w - 4) = 32$, I found that there was no solution in the real numbers.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but was assuming that "b. The dimensions of the backyard" was referring to the dimensions of the backyard before the pool was put in. Is your second equation $(h−4)(w−4)=32$ assuming that the backyard area without a pool needs to remain rectangular after the pool has been put in? I don't see why this would have to be the case.

Comment: My attempt did not work since it does not allow for the possibility that $h = 4~\text{m}$ or that $w = 4~\text{m}$.